# Wordpress moved to a new server with a new databank. Just Theme no plugins. Site worked for minutes then went offline. cant login. Server says 408

Tags: hosting

As mentioned in the title; we moved our site to a new server with a new databank. Apache conf were only modified to address the new databank. We only installed the site on the new server, installed the theme and left all plugins. The server sends a 408 answer.

Did someone have the same problem? Any recommendations?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A 408 suggests an issue with the server itself. You can test this by loading the readme.html file and seeing if it still happens ( since it's a static HTML file no WP files are loaded )

Comment: Thanks the site works again!